# Parser Error on run newly added webpage

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have add a new webpage in `solution`. 
when I try to run, it shows an Error like below. [image]
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The `Inherits` attribute value is the name of the class which inherits `Page` in the backend.

Also the path has to be correct. So go on and make some changes.